# Can a quantum computing advantage exist in a deterministic universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

Is a deterministic universe with nonlocal hidden variables incompatible with the quantum superpositioning of states that is required for quantum computing?

Comment: Yes, there are nonlocal hidden variables theories which give the same results as far as my knowledge goes. You may like to see pilot wave theory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot_wave_theory)

Comment: I assumed that pilot wave theory is fully deterministic, and therefore forbids superposition?

Comment: No, it is a non local hidden variable theory, which means that everything is deterministic but information can travel faster than the speed of light

Comment: ... and therefore forbids superposition?

Comment: I don't exactly know the whole theory but the results they give are both identical. Therefore a quantum computing advantage will still exist. You would have to check if they use superposition in the theory